# Expandable table row to read more text in Angular

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4

Hi I have an Angular8 project and there is a table with one of the fields that has a lot of text(sometimes over a hundred texts). I would like some javascript code or any already built js component that can help expand or collapse the row when clicking on a read more sign at the end of the text(only part of the text is showing when the table initial load). When expanded it should have a read less sign at the end, that will collapse the row when clicked upon. I have searched in the web but not helping.

```
    <h1>
    Key Fields
</h1>

<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover table-lg">
    <thead>
        <tr class="table-primary">
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Description</th>
            <th>Format</th>
            <th>Format Notes</th>
            <th>Xml Tag</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let keyfield of keyfields">
            <td>{{keyfield.keyName | uppercase }}</td>
            <td>{{keyfield.description}}</td>
            <td>{{keyfield.format}}</td>
            <td>{{keyfield.formatNotes}}</td>
            <td>{{keyfield.xmL_Tag}}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

<div class="d-flex justify-content-between p-2">
    <ngb-pagination [collectionSize]="collectionSize" [(page)]="page" [pageSize]="pageSize" (pageChange)="loadPage($event)">
    </ngb-pagination>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest writing your own. My site uses a couple versions of this for different screen types so here's a couple solutions.

## Logic

No matter what, you first need a switch to determine which sections are expanded.

#### Expand Any

Give your `keyfields` object an `expanded` boolean. This way each ngFor object holds its own "is open" switch.

#### Expan only One

Create a new public variable in your component that has the *index* of the expanded section.

(for this you need to use the ngFor index syntax):

```
<tr *ngFor="let keyfield of keyfields; index as i">
```

## HTML

Angular has many solutions for what you want and it's really preference. My site uses angular animations and it also uses standard scss for the mobile version (up to you).

For both, the solution is the same. Write styles to *hide* your content; use component logic to set the current state (animated or css).

#### Animations

Here the table has automatic height.

```
@Component({
...
    animations: [
        trigger('keyfieldExpanded', [
            state('collapsed', style({height: '0px', minHeight: '0'})),
            state('expanded', style({height: '*'})),
            transition('expanded <=> collapsed', animate('225ms cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.0, 0.2, 1)')),
        ]),
    ],
})
```

and then something like this for your html:

```
<td class="element-detail" [@keyfieldExpanded]="keyfield.expanded ? 'expanded' : 'collapsed'">
expanded content here
</td>
```

#### CSS

This is the easier solution. If you don't wan't an animation, just use the hidden attribute, ngclass, or ngstyle.

All of these can use the same switch: `keyfields.expanded` or `i == expanded` if you go for the expand only one option.

## Read More

With my suggestion this is actually pretty simple.

(taken from your code above):

```
<tr *ngFor="let keyfield of keyfields">
    <td>{{keyfield.keyName | uppercase }}</td>
    <td>{{keyfield.description}}</td>
    <td>{{keyfield.format}}</td>
    <td>{{keyfield.formatNotes}}</td>
    <td>{{keyfield.xmL_Tag}}</td>
    <td [hidden]="keyfield.expanded == true"><button (click)="keyfield.expanded = true">read more</button></td>
    <td [@detailExpand]="keyfield.expanded ? 'expanded' : 'collapsed'">
        <p>{{keyfield.expandedContent}}</p>
        <button (click)="keyfield.expanded = false">read less</button>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: I suggest adding more flare to your html (I just wrote this from scratch so sorry if there are spelling mistakes). If you need an example using the "Only One" option or the "CSS" option, let me know.